# WSO2 API Manager schema validation fails when body is JSONArray

Tags: wso2-api-manager, json-schema-validator

I enabled schema validation in the WSO2 API Manager and on any successful call it comes back with this error message:

`<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>500</am:code><am:message>Bad Response</am:message><am:description>Schema validation failed in the Response: #: expected type: JSONArray, found: JSONObject, </am:description></am:fault>`

When I disable the schema validation, the response has this format (I have replaced most fields and values):
`[{"myListId":"1234","externalReference":"11111","ttNumber":"0222","totalNumber":5,"statusType":"123"}]`

This looks to me like a valid JSONArray, so I am surprised at this message. How can I troubleshoot further to understand where it is going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the WSO2 API Manager version that you are using in your environment? There was a bug in the earlier API Manager version as reported in [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8079)